# Sending mail from my domain in C#.Net

Tags: c#

I want to send mail from my office domain address in C#.Net. I have written below code

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("muthukrishnan.ramasamy@xxxxxxxx.com", "muthukrishnan.ramasamy@xxxxxxx.com");
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("webmail.xxxxxxx.com", 443);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("muthukrishnan.ramasamy@xxxxxxx.com", "xxxxxxxxx");
            mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
            mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
            client.Send(mail);
        }
```

**I got exception as follows**

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The operation has timed out.

Please help on this. How to I resolve this.

Comment: It isn't a c# issue but a networking issue. The server you're trying to send the mail to isn't reachable via SMTP. So check routing/firewalls for errors.

Comment: Obviously you're trying to use the server "webmail.xxxxxxx.com" .. which I guess does not have an SMTP server, try to check with your sys admin regarding the details of the SMTP server

Comment: @Bishoy, I will check with my sys admin. Any other approach to send mail from c#.Net?

Comment: The only other approach is to use a 3rd party service like SendGrid or MailChimp, they give you an API to use for sending emails but will require that you verify your domain name

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **MailKit** *(A cross-platform .NET library for IMAP, POP3, and SMTP)*

Install-Package MailKit

```
using System;

using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit;
using MimeKit;

namespace TestClient {
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var message = new MimeMessage ();
            message.From.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Joey Tribbiani", "joey@friends.com"));
            message.To.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Mrs. Chanandler Bong", "chandler@friends.com"));
            message.Subject = "How you doin'?";

            message.Body = new TextPart ("plain") {
                Text = @"Hey Chandler,

I just wanted to let you know that Monica and I were going to go play some paintball, you in?

-- Joey"
            };

            using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
                client.Connect ("smtp.friends.com", 587, false);

                // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
                // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove ("XOAUTH2");

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate ("joey", "password");

                client.Send (message);
                client.Disconnect (true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[for more info](http://www.mimekit.net/)

Comment: MimeKit is open source under the MIT license and is free for commercial use.

Comment: I agree, MailKit is excellent. Using a ProtocolLogger with the SmtpClient may help diagnose issues when communicating with the SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending an email through another email (example: GMAIL). That way you can diagnose if it is networking/code problem. Although this sounds like a networking/email domain setup problem to me.

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("test@gmail.com", "Test Email");
var toAddress = new MailAddress(MailDetails.senderMail, "");
const string fromPassword = "password";
string subject = "" //your subject line
string body = "" // your body
var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
Host = "smtp.gmail.com", //example
Port = 587,
EnableSsl = true,
DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
Timeout = 20000
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
Subject = subject,
Body = body
})
{
 try
{
smtp.Send(message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This code is similiar to yours. Try this

```
  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
  smtp.Port = 443; 
  smtp.EnableSsl = true;
  smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 
  smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
  smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("muthukrishnan.ramasamy@xxxxxxx.com", "xxxxxxxxx");  
  smtp.Host = "webmail.xxxxxxx.com";

  MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
  mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("muthukrishnan.ramasamy@xxxxxxxx.com");
  mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("muthukrishnan.ramasamy@xxxxxxx.com"));

  mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
  mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
  mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
  smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Similar code, not work.

Answer (score -3):

It may be problem with smtp server connection .please check your smtp is connected.

```
cmd -> ping webmail.xxxxxxx.com
```

Comment: After pinging I got like this.. Its connecting 
`Pinging webmail.xxxxxxx.com [172.xx.xxx.xxx] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 172.xx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=254
Reply from 172.xx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=254
Reply from 172.xx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=254
Reply from 172.xx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=254

Ping statistics for 172.xx.xxx.xxx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms`

Comment: Pinging the hostname like this is useless as "ping" uses the ICMP protocol which has no concept of ports and the code in question is trying to open an SMTP connection on port 443.